# Can "L" sound be shared by its previous and next vowel? Ex: bellow "/ˈbel.ləʊ/", color "/ˈkʌl.lər/"?

Tags: pronunciation

It seems that no one has brought this issue up.

That is, when you search the IPA of words like "*bellow*" & "*color*" you will see "`/ˈbeloʊ/`" & "`/ˈkʌlər/`" respectively ([Source1](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bellow_1?q=bellow) & [Source2](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/color?q=color))

However, when I listen to them I feel like they should be "`/ˈbel.loʊ/`" & "`/ˈkʌl.lər/`". They don't sound like "`/ˈbe.loʊ/`" & "`/ˈkʌ.lər/`".

**Note:** `/be/` & `/bel/` are very different because for the former you don't need to put the tip of your tongue to the gum ridge after finish saying, but for the latter, you do.

So,
*Can "**L**" sound be shared by its previous and next vowel?* Ex: bellow 
"`/ˈbel.ləʊ/`", color "`/ˈkʌl.lər/`"?

And

*What about other consonants like "**M**", "**N**", etc*?

*Do they adhere to this principle?*

Comment: We don't actually pronounce two /l/s in these words, so /ˈbel.loʊ/ would be technically wrong (which is why you don't see two /l/s in the IPA). But it's hard to assign the /l/ to a single vowel.

Comment: @Peter /*be*/ & /*bel*/ are very different because for the former you don't need to put the tip of your tongue to the gum ridge after finish saying but for the latter you do

Answer (score 2):

The single [l] in "bellow" goes at the end of the first syllable, when it's pronounced normally, with no stress on the second syllable: [ˈbɛl.oʊ]. A double [l] in pronunciation has been reported for some people for the adverb "coolly", which (for them) is contrasted with the word "cooly": [ˈkul.li] / [ˈkul.i].  But that's because the two [l]s are in different morphemes, "cool" and "-ly".  English does not have double l within a morpheme.

Some might have double [n] in a word like "unneeded", because, as with "coolly", the [n]s are in different morphemes, "un-" and "needed".

I suppose I should mention that there was a popular view among some linguists on our East Coast, for a time, that in some cases consonants are "ambisyllabic", meaning that they are shared between a preceding and a following syllable. Stupid theory.

Comment: I have double consonants in both *coolly* and *unneeded*. I'm sure I could think of other examples but not of the top of my head. (Southern UK)

Comment: But if you pronounce *coolly* and *cooly* differently, shouldn't you put the /l/ with the second syllable in *cooly* [ˈku.li]? Because *cooly* rhymes with *truly*, where the /l/ has to be in the second syllable, since it's its own morpheme.

Comment: I don't think I do pronounce *coolly* and *cooly* differently, personally.  I think you are right to expect that an [l] in the same syllable as preceding [u] would affect the pronunciation of the vowel.  I didn't really follow the rest of your comment.  (For me, *cruel* has two syllables, and *cruelly* has three.)  I don't agree that [l] of *truly* is, or has to be, in the second syllable.

Comment: @Greg: you're probably right about *truly*. The [l] doesn't have to be in the second syllable because pronunciation doesn't always follow morphemes.  I pronounce *clueless, truly, cooly, foolish* all the same, where the /u/ is not *l*-influenced, while *coolly, cool, fooling, fool, cruelly* all have *l*-influenced vowels. (And both *cruel* and *cruelly* usually have two syllables.) So I was generalizing from the way I speak.

Comment: @PeterShor, Is this l-influenced /u/ lax?  How about the examples *pull, *pulling, *pool, *pooling?

Comment: No, they're different. *Pool* has a slight diphthong, so it's something like /puəl/ (but it's different from *fuel* /fju.əl/ which has two syllables).